# Pythonic way to sparsely randomly populate array?

Tags: python, arrays, random

Problem:
Populate a 10 x 10 array of zeros randomly with 10 1's, 20 2's, 30 3's.

**I don't actually have to use an array, rather I just need coordinates for the positions where the values would be. It's just easier to think of in terms of an array.**

I have written several solutions for this, but they all seem to be non-straight forward and non-pythonic. I am hoping someone can give me some insight. My method has been using a linear array of 0--99, choosing randomly (np.random.choice) 10 values, removing them from the array, then choosing 20 random values. After that, I convert the linear positions into (y,x) coordinates.

```
import numpy as np

dim = 10
grid = np.arange(dim**2)

n1 = 10
n2 = 20
n3 = 30

def populate(grid, n, dim):
    pos = np.random.choice(grid, size=n, replace=False)
    yx = np.zeros((n,2))
    for i in xrange(n):
        delPos = np.where(grid==pos[i])
        grid = np.delete(grid, delPos)
        yx[i,:] = [np.floor(pos[i]/dim), pos[i]%dim]
    return(yx, grid)

pos1, grid = populate(grid, n1, dim)
pos2, grid = populate(grid, n2, dim)
pos3, grid = populate(grid, n3, dim)
```

**Extra**
Suppose when I populate the 1's, I want them all on one half of the "array." I can do it using my method (sampling from grid[dim**2/2:]), but I haven't figured out how to do the same with the other suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a list of all coordinates, [`shuffle`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle) that list and take the first 60 of those (10 + 20 + 30):

```
>>> import random
>>> coordinates = [(i, j) for i in xrange(10) for j in xrange(10)]
>>> random.shuffle(coordinates)
>>> coordinates[:60]
[(9, 5), (6, 9), (1, 5), ..., (0, 2), (5, 9), (2, 6)]
```

You can then use the first 10 to insert the 10 values, the next 20 for the 20 values and the remaining for the 30 values.

Answer (score 3):

To generate the array, you can use [`numpy.random.choice`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html).

```
np.random.choice([0, 1, 2, 3], size=(10,10), p=[.4, .1, .2, .3])
```

Then you can convert to coordinates. Note that `numpy.random.choice` generates a random sample using probabilities `p`, and thus you are not guaranteed to get the *exact* proportions in `p`.

**Extra**

If you want to have all the `1`s on a particular side of the array, you can generate two random arrays and then [`hstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html#numpy.hstack) them. The trick is to slightly modify the probabilities of each number on each side.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: rem = .1/3 # amount to de- / increase the probability for non-1s
In [3]: A = np.random.choice([0, 1, 2, 3], size=(5, 10),
                              p=[.4-rem, .2, .2-rem, .3-rem])
In [4]: B = np.random.choice([0, 2, 3], size=(5, 10), p=[.4+rem, .2+rem, .3+rem])
In [5]: M = np.hstack( (A, B) )
In [6]: M
Out[1]: 
array([[1, 1, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 3, 3, 2, 0],
       [0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 1, 3, 1, 3, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 2, 3],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 1, 2, 2, 0, 3, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0],
       [3, 2, 3, 0, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3],
       [3, 3, 0, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3]])
```

Here, because I'm putting *all* the `1`s on the left, I double the probability of `1` and decrease the probability of each number equally. The same logic applies when creating the other side.

Comment: Wow, even though I've **used** the `p` argument before, it never occurred to me to use it in this application. Your solution is simply and eloquent, thanks you!

Comment: I think p[0] should be 0.4

Comment: @mititan8: I've added an Extra to my question, and I am trying to figure out how to modify your answer such that it works in that instance. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Actually, this approach won't give you EXACTLY 10 1's, 20 2's, 30 3's - it will maintain these probabilities only on average. To check, count occurrences in the array you are getting. If you need exact number, you should use Simeon's approach

Comment: @ngimel: good point, I've updated my answer to make this readily apparent.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is anymore "pythonic", but here's something I came up with using part of Simeon's answer.

```
import random

dim = 10
n1 = 10
n2 = 20
n3 = 30

coords = [[i,j] for i in xrange(dim) for j in xrange(dim)]

def setCoords(coords, n):
    pos = []
    for i in xrange(n):
        random.shuffle(coords)
        pos.append(coords.pop())
    return(coords, pos)

coordsTmp, pos1 = setCoords(coords[dim**2/2:], n1)
coords = coords[:dim**2/2] + coordsTmp
coords, pos2 = setCoords(coords, n2)
coords, pos3 = setCoords(coords, n3)
```